# Find if the limit of $\lim_{ (x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

If we approach $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ on $y=mx^n, n \in R, n>2$

Then we get

$\lim_{ (x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x(mx^n)}{\sqrt{x^2+m^2x^{2n}}}$
$\lim_{ (x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{(mx^n)}{\sqrt{1+m^2x^{2n-2}}} =0$

This suggests that the limit does exists and is 0, but how do I show this formally?

Thanks.

Comment: One way: polar coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $-1\le \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le 1$.

Comment: Nice remark, then by the squeeze theorem we can show that the limit is 0 when we multiply by x through out and take the limit as (x,y) -> (0,0). Im curious, how did you realize this? Is it from practice and experience? Thanks.

Comment: @CivilSigma: You are welcome.

Comment: The squeeze theorem is a theorem for functions of one variable, not two variables.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right| = 
\frac{|x|\cdot|y|}{|\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}|} \leq 
\frac{|\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}|\cdot|\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}|}{|\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}|}
$$

Comment: Why is $|x|=|y|=|\sqrt{ {x^2+y^2}}|$ ?

Comment: note that's an ***in***equality.

Comment: I don't follow, why is it so?

Comment: $|x| = \sqrt{x^2} \leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$